# JUnit Failed Assertion on Camel Route

Tags: junit, apache-camel, blueprint

I'm making a simple Camel Test Case for my camel route coded on blueprint.
This route transforms a xml File into Json format.
The route does it well, and I have no problems with the transformation.
Then I'm also looking to learn and use JUnit Test on my routes, by making a Camel test Case, but it fails on the assertion. I can't see what I'm doing wrong, or the differences that the trace is giving me. Can you tell me what is wrong with the test??

The next is the Trace I've got.

```
   java.lang.AssertionError: mock://output Message with body {"name" : "Frank Jarrod","custId" : "F475678678","vip" : 6,"stockId" : "ABC","shares" : 20,"cost" : null} was expected but not found in [{
  "name" : "Frank Jarrod",
  "custId" : "F475678678",
  "vip" : 6,
  "stockId" : "ABC",
  "shares" : 20,
  "cost" : null
}]
    at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.fail(MockEndpoint.java:1394)
```

...

And here is the Test class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author miguelangelmorales
 *
 */
public class Lab02XmlTest extends CamelBlueprintTestSupport {

    // TODO Create test message bodies that work for the route(s) being tested
    // Expected message bodies
    protected Object[] expectedBodies = {
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
            + "<stocktrading>"
            + "<name>Frank Jarrod</name>"
            + "<custId>F475678678</custId>"
            + "<vip>6</vip>"
            + "<stockId>ABC</stockId>+"
            + "<shares>20</shares>+"
            + "</stocktrading>  "
                        };

    protected Object[] expectedResultBodies2 = {
            "{\"name\" : \"Frank Jarrod\",\"custId\" : \"F475678678\",\"vip\" : 6,\"stockId\" : \"ABC\",\"shares\" : 20,\"cost\" : null}" 
            };

    // Templates to send to input endpoints
    @Produce(uri = "file:myxml?delete=true")
    protected ProducerTemplate inputEndpoint;
    // Mock endpoints used to consume messages from the output endpoints and then perform assertions
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:output")
    protected MockEndpoint outputEndpoint;

    @Test
    public void testCamelRoute() throws Exception {
        // Create routes from the output endpoints to our mock endpoints so we can assert expectations
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("file:donexml").to(outputEndpoint);
            }
        });

        // Define some expectations

        // TODO Ensure expectations make sense for the route(s) we're testing
        outputEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(expectedResultBodies2);

        // Send some messages to input endpoints
        for (Object expectedBody : expectedBodies) {
            inputEndpoint.sendBody(expectedBody);
        }

        // Validate our expectations
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBlueprintDescriptor() {
        return "OSGI-INF/blueprint/Lab02.xml";
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try putting newline characters after each key/value? Junit is very particular about spacing.

Comment: @midnghtblue I've tried putting spaces and newlines to match the output and the required input on the trace, and it didn't help at first. But looking at my camel route the output is giving me has a "pretty format" ( <json prettyPrint="true" library="Jackson" collectionTypeName="example.TradeOrder"/>
 ), then I've changed this to false and everything works fine. Thanks for the answer!!!